# vfptr / vftable changes basetype when class destructor calls parent destructor

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I'm using visual studio 2008, c++, win32, no dot net.

I've got a problem with virtual functions that are called in the destructor of a parent.
For example, take the classes a and b. Class a has a virtual function called Hello(); When called, it prints hello.

Class b inherits from class a and also implements the function Hello. When called, it prints world.

In the destructor of class a the function Hello is called. When class b is deleted, the destructor of b is first called, then the destructor of a. In the destructor of a the function Hello is called, except the it's the implementation associated with class a, not class b.

Code for this example below this line.

```
class a{
public:
  virtual void Hello();
  a();
  ~a();
};

a::a(){
};

a::~a(){
  Hello();
}

void a::Hello(){
  printf("hello\n");
}

class b:public a{
public:
  virtual void Hello();
  b();
  ~b();  
};

b::b(){
}

b::~b(){
}

void b::Hello(){
  printf("world\n");
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){  
  a* exampleA=new a();
  b* exampleB=new b(); 
  exampleA->Hello();
  exampleB->Hello();
  delete exampleA;
  delete exampleB;
  return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
hello
world
hello
hello
```

When I place a breakpoint in the destructor of class b, the __vfptr in the local variables
are as follows:

```
__vfptr
  [0x0]    0x002314ce b::Hello(void)
```

When a step through and enter de destructor of class a, the __vfptr in the local variables has changed to:

```
__vfptr
  [0x0]   0x0024c864 a::Hello(void)
```

This is normal I quess? And there is no (correct) way to call the b's implementation of Hello inside the destructor of class a ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is the order of destruction:

- first, the derived class `b` is destroyed
- then the base class `a`.
  It wouldn't be safe for `~a()` to call methods (virtual ones) from the destroyed `b`, as such methods could refer/make use of class members inside `b` that have already been destroyed

I also recommend this article by Scott Meyers:
http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html

Also, I subscribe to Mark B's solution. Also Kerrek SB's quote confirms this as standard, well defined behavior.

Comment: +1 As this is the only answer that explains why rather than state what the OP seems to know already.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. There's no way to b's `Hello` inside the destructor of `a`. The same applies for constructors as well.

If you really need something called polmorphically at destruction you can enforce two-ohase destruction with a private/protected destructor and a public destroy method that first calls the virtual function and then self-destructs.

Answer (score 1):

According to 12.7/4,

> When a virtual function is called directly or indirectly from a constructor or from a destructor, [...] the function called is the final overrider **in the constructor’s or destructor’s class and not one overriding it in a more-derived class**

and thus the behaviour is well-defined and you call the member function in the class itself, and there is no dynamic dispatch.

Comment: What's 12.7/4, I'm not getting the reference.

Comment: @user2007560: It's the relevant section of the C++ standard.